# How to implement Slide-out Menu Slider like Facebook iPhone app with UITabbar in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uislider

I want to implement Facebook iPhone app like Menu slider with UITabbar using Swift but after applying navigation controller from Appdelegate, Tabbabr gets removed. Any suggestions.
Thanx in Advance.

Comment: I use https://github.com/evnaz/ENSwiftSideMenu

Comment: @Mark-AR, Thank you. It work's with UITabBar also.